# use regex for get values java

Tags: java, regex

i want to how to get separate text from  group of contents in java..

example

```
String a = "area href=\"hai.com\"  jkjfkjs </area> ndkjfkjsdfj dfjkdsjfl jkdf dljflsd fljdf kd;fsd a href=\"hoo.com\"  sdf</a> jisdjfi jdojfis joij";
```

i would like to get href link only..

how to write regex..

thanks and advance

Comment: I don't see how do you get `href="value only"` from something which clearly does not contain one.

Comment: This looks like an invalid string.

Comment: I made the string valid, the idea behind this was understandable.

Answer (score 4):

That should do the trick.

```
String text = ...
Matcher matcher Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"").matcher(text);
while (matcher.find())
{
   String hrefcontent = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
String textToSearch = "[Some text to search through]";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"")
```